# Error: code too large in Generated R file for library module

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, r.java-file, android-multidex

Our app has got more than 12K entries in the generated R file and it is working fine as an android application project.

Once we convert that to an android library project and it is throwing "error: code too large"

It is referring to the first line of the id class generated in R file.

```
===========================================
> Task :features:packageName FAILED
/Users/StudioProjects/app/packageName/build/generated/source/r/app/debug/packagename/R.java:8128: error: code too large
        public static int ALT = 0x7f0c0001;
===========================================

line no : 8127         public static final class id {
                              public static int ALT = 0x7f0c0001;
                              .....
                              .....
Line no : 20558        }

===========================================
```

We have copied the class id to a text file and its size was 1.3 MB. 
The word count of the id class is 62K. I tried enabling MutiDex and ProGuard, but still having this issue.

Comment: Hi, have you resovled this problem?

Comment: We resovled this problem by changing 'implementation' or 'api' to 'compileOnly'. The reason is that the R.java file is too large. After changing dependencies way of new dependent component, the R.java file shrinks from 3M to 2.6M.